# Update all documents with geoip processor

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm reading this guide https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geoip-processor.html

And I'd like to update all existing documents in the index, but according to the guide I need to provide the IP again to update the document.

What is the recommended way to inject GEO data to all existing documents? And should I update all the document when GEOIP database is updated?

Answer (score 0):

**Q1**: What is the recommended way to inject GEO data to all existing documents?

**A1**: [update by query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html)

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/geoip
{
  "description" : "Add geoip info",
  "processors" : [
    {
      "geoip" : {
        "field" : "ip"
      }
    }
  ]
}
PUT my-index-000001/_doc/1
{
  "ip": "89.160.20.128"
}

POST my-index-000001/_update_by_query?pipeline=geoip&conflicts=proceed
```

**Q2**: And should I update all the document when GEOIP database is updated?

**A2**: Yes, you need to run the update by query again.